# On Google Chrome, how to change my bookmarks on the bookmark bar back to unsorted order?

Tags: google-chrome

On Google Chrome, I had my bookmark bar arranged with different folders and bookmarks, but today (Dec 17, 2021), all the items are sort alphabetically and I didn't do that.

Is there a way to tell it to go back to the previous state?

Comment: Are you synchronizing your Google Chrome profile across multiple devices by chance?

Comment: I happen to be sync'ing between devices. Are you saying I can go to the other computer, move the YouTube in front of my Amazon, and then now hopefully, that change will refresh this "sorted" situation?  That's too bad, I already moved the YouTube back to the correct position on this computer and I guess my other devices will follow suit instead (all become sorted)

Comment: So put those machines offline, stop synchronizing on those machines, and export your bookmarks.  This will allow you to import them on the original machine. Anyways I am not saying, what you suggested, the reason I asked I suspect that the other machine is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are synced across multiple devices (like Ramhound commented) or [saved your bookmarks into a file onto your computer](https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-export-save-import-bookmarks-in-chrome), then you'll have to resort to them manually.